# Sax Parsing: How to Return an ArrayList with its containing data?

Tags: java, android, saxparser

Here is my code:

```
public class XMLGettersSetters {
    private ArrayList<String> country = new ArrayList<String>();

    public ArrayList<String> getCountry() {
        return country;
    }

    public void setCountry(String countryValue) {
        this.country.add(countryValue);
        Log.i("Countries", countryValue);
    }
```

In LogCat it shows all the data, but when I am returning it and trying to show it in a ListView it is just showing the last value of the list, not all. Am I missing something?

Comment: I think your missing some code here man. What you gave doesn't seem complete and I can't help you with what I got

Comment: I am setting the country from another class and the values ar being added in the arraylist, but when i m getting this returned arraylist its showing the last value of what it gets, but in the log cat it shows all the values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just some points with what I see so far.

1. Your return type for getCountry should be ArrayList you are missing the type.
2. I would call it setCountry because you aren't setting, you are adding to the list.

Perhaps it's something to do with the length you are returning in your adapter?

Comment: I m setting the value from another class, and its showing all the value in logcat, but when i return it, it shows the one value, i think its overwriting the value, how to solve it?

Comment: yeah. So without the ability to view the code I can only guess.  And my guessing are you are return only one item and not the entire array. Check your return type. or your length is set to 1 somewhere so it's only giving you one element.